# Firestore database with Algolia

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I want to implement a search funtionality in my app and I have at least a hundreds existing documents from my Firestore database that I want to index in Algolia. My question is, how can I convert it to a JsonObject so that I could import it to Algolia?

Answer (score 0):

For data sync between Algolia and Firestore, your best bet is the [official extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/algolia-firestore-algolia-search), but that only syncs new docs as they're added to your store.

There's a solid example of importing existing records using a Cloud Function in [this blog](https://ferdinandmarq.medium.com/how-to-import-data-from-firebase-firestore-into-algolia-using-cloud-functions-4c399fac326b).